# Background image not showing up with React + TailwindCSS

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Im trying to use Tailwind with React to show a background image.
My config is like the follow:

```
const white_bg = require("../../assets/images/wave_light.svg"); // Import using relative path
const black_bg = require("../../assets/images/wave_black.svg"); // Import using relative path

module.exports = {
  purge: [
    "src/**/*.js",
    "src/**/*.jsx",
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "public/**/*.html",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: (theme) => ({
        "white-landing": `url(${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + white_bg})`,
        "black-landing": `url(${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + black_bg})`,
      }),
    },
textColor: {
      "nav-text": "#eaeaea",
    },
    fontFamily: {
      header: ["Poppins", "sans-serif"],
      body: ["Poppins", "sans-serif"],
    },
    boxShadow: {
      header: "0px 0px 50px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)",
      card: "0px 0px 25px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)",
    },
```

And calling the classes in the html:

```
<div className="bg-white-landing white-landing box-border h-full">
```

None of my custom classes seem to work... Any help?

Comment: Try it this way

backgroundImage: (theme) => ({
        "white-landing": "url('assets/img/white_bg')",
        "black-landing":  "url('assets/img/black_bg')",
      }),

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this ticket?

[Tailwind css backgroundImage doesn't work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63658218/tailwind-css-backgroundimage-doesnt-work-for-me)

> The background image functionality of tailwindcss has been released in version 1.7.0.

Could be to do with the version you are running.

Update: I have found a way around this by adding a url-encoded svg inside tailwind.css like so:

```
// hardcoded svg background
  .example-selector{
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='23' viewBox='0 0 23 24'%3E%3Cdefs/%3E%3Cg fill='none' fill-rule='evenodd'%3E%3Cpath fill='currentColor' fill-rule='nonzero' d='M22.545 21.077l-.028-.03-6.048-6.305c1.05-1.57 1.59-3.434 1.59-5.329C18.06 4.233 14 0 9.03 0 4.06 0 0 4.233 0 9.413c0 5.18 4.06 9.414 9.03 9.414 1.817 0 3.606-.592 5.11-1.658l6.049 6.305c.624.681 1.675.71 2.328.03.625-.651.653-1.747.028-2.427zM9.03 16.28c-3.635 0-6.588-3.079-6.588-6.868S5.395 2.546 9.03 2.546c3.634 0 6.587 3.078 6.587 6.867 0 3.79-2.953 6.868-6.587 6.868z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a class and add the `background-image` globally in the `index.css`

Answer (score 0):

changing the path has worked for me!

```
theme: {
    backgroundImage: {
      'pack-train': "url('../public/images/packTrain.jpg')",
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I read in the documentation like this

```
theme:{
  extend:{
    backgroundImage:{
       'white-landing':'url(../../assets/images/wave_light.svg)'
              },
          }
      }
```

and this worked for me, maybe it can help

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this [blog](https://www.ibrahima-ndaw.com/blog/tailwindcss-background-image-with-dark-mode-support/) help me
so after you add custom backgroundImage to your tailwind.config.js
ps. don't for get quotation mark

```
theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        // if you img file is in public folder just use '/ + img-file-name'
        "custom-name": "url('path/to/your/imgFile.png')",
      },
    },
```

then add 'bg-custom-name' to the div you want to have that bg-img

```
// your component
<div className='bg-custom-name ...'>
    < - child - >
</div>
```